# C element of struct inside strunct not retaining assigned value

Tags: c, pointers, linear-programming, glpk

Here's my structs :

```
typedef struct Bounds Bounds;
struct Bounds
{
    int type;
    double lb;
    double ub;
};

typedef struct HelperGlpk HelperGlpk;
struct HelperGlpk
{
    double *matrix_coefs;
    double *obj_coefs;
    Bounds *row_bounds;
    Bounds *col_bounds;
    int *column_of_coef;
    int *row_of_coef;
    int cpt_coef;
    int cpt_contrainte;
};
```

here's my function generate_contrainte_1 :

```
void genere_contrainte_1(int i, int j, HelperGlpk *helper_glpk, Baie baie){
    helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_ouverture_serveur(i)].type = GLP_DB;
    helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_ouverture_serveur(i)].lb = 0;
    helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_ouverture_serveur(i)].ub = 1;

    helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_connexion(i, j, baie.nbr_serveur)].type = GLP_LO;
    helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_connexion(i, j, baie.nbr_serveur)].lb = 0;
    helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_connexion(i, j, baie.nbr_serveur)].ub = 0;
```

}

and here's how I call generate_contrainte_1 :

```
HelperGlpk helper_glpk;
helper_glpk.col_bounds = malloc((nbr_colums + 1) * sizeof(Bounds));
helper_glpk.row_bounds = malloc((nbr_rows + 1) * sizeof(Bounds));  

for(i = 1; i <= baie.nbr_serveur; i++)
    for(j = 1; j <= baie.nbr_client; j++)
        genere_contrainte_1(i, j, &helper_glpk, baie);
```

The problem is that the value inside

`helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_ouverture_serveur(i)].type`

is not saved outside my function and I get a wrong value when I try to access it.

How can I solve this problem ?

Edit :

```
int index_ouverture_serveur(int i){
    return i;
}

int index_connexion(int i, int j, size_t nbr_serveur){
    return j * nbr_serveur + i;
}
```

Edit 2 :
I added some printf to know where the error come from, it didn't help me but it might help you :

```
    helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_ouverture_serveur(i)].type = GLP_DB;
    helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_ouverture_serveur(i)].lb = 0;
    helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_ouverture_serveur(i)].ub = 1;
    printf("col_bounds[%d].type = %d\n", index_ouverture_serveur(i), helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_ouverture_serveur(i)].type);

    helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_connexion(i, j, baie.nbr_serveur)].type = GLP_LO;
    helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_connexion(i, j, baie.nbr_serveur)].lb = 0;
    helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_connexion(i, j, baie.nbr_serveur)].ub = 0;

    printf("col_bounds[%d].type = %d\n", index_connexion(i, j, baie.nbr_serveur), helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_ouverture_serveur(i)].type);
```

here's what I get :

```
col_bounds[1].type = 4
col_bounds[51].type = 4
col_bounds[1].type = 4
col_bounds[101].type = 4
col_bounds[1].type = 4
col_bounds[151].type = 4
col_bounds[1].type = 4
[...]
col_bounds[4900].type = 4
col_bounds[50].type = 4
col_bounds[4950].type = 4
col_bounds[50].type = 4
col_bounds[5000].type = 4
col_bounds[50].type = 4
col_bounds[5050].type = 4
```

now I do this printf outside my function :

```
for(i = 1; i <= nbr_colums; i++)
        printf("type[%d] : %d\n", i, helper_glpk.col_bounds[i].type);
```

and this is what I get :

```
type[1] : 2555
type[2] : 2558
type[3] : 2561
type[4] : 2564
type[5] : 2567
type[6] : 2570
type[7] : 2573
type[8] : 2576
type[9] : 2579
type[10] : 2582
type[11] : 2585
type[12] : 2588
type[13] : 2591
type[14] : 2594
type[15] : 2597
type[16] : 2600
type[17] : 2603
type[18] : 2606
type[19] : 2609
type[20] : 2612
type[21] : 2615
type[22] : 2618
type[23] : 2621
type[24] : 2624
type[25] : 2627
type[26] : 2630
type[27] : 4
type[28] : 4
type[29] : 4
type[30] : 4
[...]
type[5042] : 2
type[5043] : 2
type[5044] : 2
type[5045] : 2
type[5046] : 2
type[5047] : 2
type[5048] : 2
type[5049] : 2
type[5050] : 2
```

Comment: The way your method is and the way you call it is perfectly fine. You should look elsewhere for the error. By the way, "outside my function" is the same scope having heler_glpk, right?

Comment: Post `index_ouverture_serveur` function.

Comment: I posted index_ouverture_serveur, very simple function...

Comment: outside my function mean just after calling my function

Comment: I just updated my answer with some printf for debug

Comment: It is possible that you are overwriting the values yourself. Is your `malloc` big enough? Depends on your exact numeric values of `baie.nbr_serveur` and `nbr_colums`, which you haven't supplied. Is it possible to run the code with some small value like 3 and 4, respectively for these variables. Also a small value for number of rows.